# error while getting input from a file

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

main function:

```
main = do
  x <- getLine
  lines <- replicateM x getLine
  print $ lines
```

the error I am getting:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Int'
Expected type: Int
  Actual type: String
In the first argument of `replicateM', namely `x'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: lines <- replicateM x getLine
```

Need a way to solve this issue.

Comment: `x` is a string (aka a list of characters) and `replicateM` needs an int - what's unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replicateM goes like `replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`
where as `getLine :: IO String`
"x" needs to be `Int` but `getLine` returns an `IO String`,
You can do `read x :: Int`:

```
main = do
  x <- getLine
  lines <- replicateM (read x :: Int) getLine
  print $ lines
```

or simply do:

```
main = do
  x <- readLn
  lines <- replicateM x getLine
  print $ lines
```

`readLn` probably gets `x` as `IO Int`

Comment: Indeed `readLn` gets `x` as `IO a` where `a` is the type which is needed in the context. Since `replicateM` requires `Int`, then the compiler infers `a ~ Int`. If `replicateM` did not fix `a` precisely, an ambiguity error would have occurred.